# What does it mean to compare classes with greater than `>` and less than `<` operators?

Tags: ruby

I have not found any description for the operators `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` in the documentation for `Object` and `Class`.

```
String > Object      # => false
BasicObject > Object # => true
String > Integer     # => nil
```

Comment: See the ruby documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E

Comment: The [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-3C) mention a nice mnemonic: _"`class A < B` implies `A < B`"_

Comment: Given a receiver `obj` that responds to a method `m`, `obj.method(:m).owner` will tell you where the method `m` is defined. For `A < B`, `A.method(:<).owner #=> Module`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When class level comparison is done, it looks for hierarchy/relationship.

`String > Object`  returns false because `Object` is ancestor for `String` class.

Similar will be followed for this hierarchy `Object -> Numeric -> Integer`

`String > Integer` returns nil because both classes do not come in same hierarchy/relationship.

Answer (score 5):

As you have found, those methods are not defined for `Object` nor for `Class`.

In your example, they are defined in `Module`, which is the parent of `Class`. Read somewhere around [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-3C).

When you want to know in which class a method is defined, use `owner`.

```
String.method(:>).owner # => Module
```

Answer (score 2):

It might not be clear at first, but `>` is actually a method, so you can try to get more info about it with the [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-method) method:

```
String.method(:>)
# #<Method: Class(Module)#>>
```

Which means that the method is defined in [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-3E) and is called on a `Class` object.

Answer (score 0):

The [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html) is used to compare.

As the classes are using it or implementing the <=> method, they can compares the receiver against another object, returning -1, 0, or +1 depending on whether the receiver is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object.

But on the class level, the hierarchy is taken in consideration.

Comment: No, it's not. `Class.ancestors
#=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: @sawa can you detail?

Comment: Can't you see that the ancestry list does not include `Comparable`?

Comment: Instances of a `Comparable` class are totally ordered. Modules (or classes) are partially ordered.

Comment: So you are saying is not about Comparable is about hierarchy? Is the last sentence in my response.